# Elastic search source filtering query for nested JSON document

Tags: elasticsearch, nosql, elasticsearch-dsl

I have the below JSON object as _source in Elastic search. I need to filter the source object based on conditions. For example, **I need only JSON with applied_as == "COMMISSION"**

```
  "_source": {
      "factor" : [
        {
          "some_amount_usd" : [
            {
              "applied_as" : "TCKT_CNT",
              "version" : "8",
              "factor_value" : "1.12",
              "start_date" : "2022-01-01"
            },
            {
              "applied_as" : "TCKT_CNT",
              "version" : "8",
              "factor_value" : "1.12",
              "start_date" : "2022-02-01"
            },
            {
              "applied_as" : "COMMISSION",
              "version" : "8",
              "factor_value" : "1.12",
              "start_date" : "2022-02-01"
            },
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
```

I am using this documentation.
https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.17/search-fields.html#source-filtering

I am currently using this query with no luck. What am I missing?

```
GET form_some_index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "factor.some_amount_usd.applied_as": "COMMISSION"
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: factor and some_amount_usd are Nested Type?

Comment: yes, they are the nested types.

Comment: do you want all itens inside some_amount_usd has applied_as = COMMISSION ?

Comment: yes, I want all items.

Comment: I updated my answer. Check if the field applied_as is keyword, if not change Term Query to Match Query.

Answer (score 0):

You can start using [Nested Query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html).

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must_not": [
        {
          "nested": {
            "path": "factor",
            "query": {
              "nested": {
                "path": "factor.some_amount_usd",
                "query": {
                  "bool": {
                    "must_not": [
                      {
                        "term": {
                          "factor.some_amount_usd.applied_as.keyword": {
                            "value": "COMMISSION"
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is not working.